# PWM large current, will it kill MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, inductance

We are looking at PWM dimming 2700 LEDs.

- 3.2V forward voltage
- 20mA current each
- Connected in parallel

This makes 54A in total. The longest stretch of cable is 7 meters (one way). Currently looking at doing this with IRLB8721.

I'm concerned the inductance of the cables might overwhelm the MOSFET. 54A in the drain, being turned on and off at a minimum of 1kHz, might it hurt it in the long run?

If it is indeed a problem, what might be some strategies to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You're vastly overestimating the current handling capabilities of the IRLB8721. While it's technically (just barely) rated for your desired current, it will dissipate more than 25 Watts when it actually conducts that much current. This is due to its 8.7 mOhms of on-resistance. 25 Watts in a TO-220 package is no joke, I'd consider it borderline uncoolable. You'd ideally use a MOSFET with an on-state resistance of 1 mOhm or less. You'll also need a capable MOSFET driver to charge and discharge the gate quickly, or else you'll suffer large switching losses.

Another problem is the wire resistance. At 54A, you'll need to use a *lot* of copper - something like 6mm² wire (or more). That's going to be quite expensive.

To combat the inductance of the attached wiring, you can use a simple free-wheeling diode - just like you would for an electromechanical relay. It should be a Schottky (or FERD) type rated for 60A or more.

Last but not least, you can make your life a lot easier if you don't just connect all of those LEDs in parallel. Instead, you could connect three in series (together with a dropper resistor), and then put 900 of those three-LED-blocks in parallel. That way, you can use 12V at 18A instead of the (rather ridiculous) 3.2V at 54A.

Comment: Yep, choosing a MOSFET by matching its current rating to your current requirement is not a good approach.

Comment: Very informative. Thank you. Would there be any significant drawback to taking that idea one step further, having 450 groups of six-LED-blocks, operating at 20-something volts? I assume that would make the circuit more efficient, especially across the MOSFET.

Comment: @mikabytes If you can use a 24V power supply, that'd be even more ideal!